# Build Error after installed @react-native-firabase/app

Tags: firebase, react-native, package, react-native-firebase, build-error

My RN version is 0.64.4 . I got "FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeLibDexDebug'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskDelegate
> There was a failure while executing work items
> > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction
> > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
> Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
> Type io.invertase.firebase.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: E:\CEYENTRA\Projects\Apartner\mobile\node_modules@react-native-firebase\app\android\build.transforms\165
> 6bf916e45db379f540528cb11db2f\transformed\classes\classes.dex, E:\CEYENTRA\Projects\Apartner\mobile\node_modules\react-native-firebase\android\build.transforms\3cbeaff57f0cc8ac42ab5a
> 458037d11a\transformed\classes\classes.dex
> " this error after installed @react-native-firebase/app & @react-native-firebase/messaging. How I fix it?

First time I used latest versions. After I got error I change the @react-native-firebase/app & @react-native-firebase/messaging versions for 12.7.5 version.But still same error